# Spearman correlation significancy test

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance, asymptotics

This is probably obvious for a statistician but I could not find to what refers 
*the asymptotic t approximation* method in the correlation test of R cor.test ?

```
?cor.test
```

> For Spearman's test, p-values are computed using algorithm AS 89 for n
>   < 1290 and exact = TRUE, otherwise via the asymptotic t approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many test statistics's distributions under the null hypothesis will approach a certain known distribution as the sample size grows to infinity. In the present case, Spearman's rank correlation approaches a $t$ distribution as $n\to\infty$.

Often one will calculate $p$ values exactly or run simulations (e.g., `?chisq.test`) for small sample sizes and rely on the asymptotic distribution for large sample sizes. See also [Large sample asymptotic/theory - Why to care about?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/58131/1352)

You may be interested in browsing the [asymptotics](/questions/tagged/asymptotics) tag.

Comment: Thanks !! It helps a lot. The cor.test R help page should be replaced by your answer !

Answer (score 3):

For the $n>1290$ case* (or when not using `exact=TRUE`), the test statistic used$^\dagger$ is this one:

$$t=r{\sqrt  {{\frac  {n-2}{1-r^{2}}}}}$$

which should be asymptotically distributed as $t_{n-2}$. [The same statistic is used when testing whether a Pearson correlation differs from 0, but the justification is different]

This statistic is discussed in the Wikipedia page for the [Spearman coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient).

It says there that

> A justification for this result relies on a permutation argument.

and the citation for this claim is Vol 2. of Kendall and Stuart (§ 31.19, 31.21)

---

* The help is slightly inaccurate; it should say $n\leq 1290$ rather than $n<1290$ for the situation when it uses AS 89.

$\dagger$ You can see for yourself that it's doing this right in the code for the Spearman part of `cor.test.default`:

> ```
>  pt(r/sqrt((1 - r^2)/(n - 2)), df = n - 2,
> ```

That's the handy thing about actually being able to see the code -- you can check for yourself exactly what it's doing

Comment: comprehensive way to explain the real things !